# Webcam: Device not found

Tags: webcam

Cheese says "no device found" when I try to use it, and no other applications can find it either. I tried the commands that I found from looking at answers to similar questions, and these are the results:

[sudo lshw --class video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0n5HA.png)

[/bin/ls -l /dev/video*;id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWTAR.png)

[sudo lshw -c multimedia *-multimedia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKyko.png)

I should also mention that the webcam works fine on Windows 10, and that I have Windows 10 dual booted on my computer along with Ubuntu.

I apologize for not including the results from the terminal as text.  When I tried, it didn't appear correctly.  This is my first time asking a question on here so I'm not very familiar with how to do it.